# MongoDB insert in multiple threads

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using MongoDB as database. So When I insert a document into the database and very shortly after I do this again, it inserts the document again (I check if the database contains the document before inserting it).  The reason it does this, I think, is that I run the update method async which means it takes some time, so at the time it checks if it contains it it's still updating it to the database.

Update method:

```
public static void updateAndInsert(final String collection, final String where, final String whereValue, final DBObject value)
{
    Utils.runAsync(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if(!contains(collection, where, whereValue))
                insert(collection, value);
            else
                db.getCollection(collection).update(new BasicDBObject(where, whereValue), new BasicDBObject("$set", value));
        }
    });
}
```

How can I make sure it only inserts it once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question without a question. Wow! `:D`

You shouln't do it that way, because there are no transactions in MongoDB. **But** you do have atomic operations on single documents.

Better use an `upsert`. Within the find part of the upsert, you specify the thing you do within your `contains` method. (Maybe have a look here: http://techidiocy.com/upsert-mongodb-java-example/ or just google for MongoDB and upsert)

This way you can do `contains`, `insert` and `update` in a single query. That's the way you should do it with MongoDB!